# Sort an list by frequency of names by using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

The original list is:

```
Cat
Dog
Mouse
Cat
Bat
Alpaca
Bat
```

The expected result:

```
Bat
Bat
Cat
Cat
Alpaca
Dog
Mouse
```

The result shows the frequency of names first then sorted alphabetically.
Could anyone help me to solve this question by using C# and LINQ?

Comment: Why "Alpaca" follows "Cat"? Is this a typo?

Comment: I want to sort the name by their frequency first

Comment: Have you looked at `orderby` in either of its forms. You are also going to need to specify a sorting rule; I can't think of one that puts _Alpaca_ where you show it

Comment: Using ```OrderByDescending```

Comment: I'd be reasonable surprised if someone knows some LINQ magic that does an _order by_ frequency in list and the by alpha sort. You need to specify something fundamental like that in your question. You can edit it to add that info. You should take the [tour] to read about how to ask a good question

Answer (score 2):

You can use group by to do this:

```
var input = new List<string> { "Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Cat", "Bat", "Alpaca", "Bat" };
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).ThenBy(x => x.Key).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/10wAPu

Comment: how to let names having more frequency at the front?